# Select multiple rows from PostGIS table where ST_Contains has multiple manual inputs

Tags: postgis, postgresql, sql

Under normal circumstances I could get the spatial intersection between a table with multipolygons and another table with point geometry using some variant of

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM ( SELECT * FROM point_geometries) s 
JOIN polygon_geometries sg ON ST_Contains(sg.geom, s.point_geom)
```

But I have a situation where instead of a table, I have a list of point geometries to input. If I only have one geometry then I can do

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM polygon_geometries 
WHERE ST_Contains(geom, '0101000020E6100000E73B8A05101056C01F1166ED49594440')
```

which returns a single row from polygon_geometries giving me exactly what I want.

Now imagine I have 100+ geometries and I want to get all the rows from polygon_geometries where ST_Contains any of the points (in theory returning up to 100 rows from polygon_geometries). Is there a way to do this that doesn't involve constructing WHERE ST_Contains(geom, string1) OR ST_Contains(geom, string2)... etc?

I'd love to be able to feed a list of the strings in, if possible. I simply can not find any examples of this.

Comment: You can convert an array of strings to row in a virtual table and join on that. This is probably more a [dba.se] issue, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two common options:

- a set of materialized `VALUES`:

  ```
  WITH
    inputs(geom) AS [MATERIALIZED] (
      VALUES
        ('<WKB>'),
        ('<WKB>'),
        ...
    )
  SELECT ply.*
  FROM   polygon_geometries AS ply
  JOIN   inputs AS inp
    ON   ST_Contains(ply.geom, ST_SetSRID(inp.geom::GEOMETRY, <SRID>)
  ;
  ```
- a table from `UNNEST`:

  ```
  WITH
    inputs AS [MATERIALIZED] (
      SELECT ST_SetSRID(wkb::GEOMETRY, <SRID>) AS geom
      FROM   UNNEST(ARRAY[
               '<WKB>',
               '<WKB>',
               ...
             ]) AS wkb
    )
  SELECT ply.*
  FROM   polygon_geometries AS ply
  JOIN   inputs AS inp
    ON   ST_Contains(ply.geom, inp.geom)
  ;
  ```

with the former being slightly faster in terms of creating the set, and the latter being more comfortable for *copy/paste*.

`MATERIALIZED` only applies to PostgreSQL >= 12.

Comment: Thank you! Both worked perfectly and I learned a few new tricks in the process!